# JSON function in Mariadb

Tags: json, mariadb

I have this json

```
{"commandName":"App\\Jobs\\PublishClass","command":"O:21:\"App\\Jobs\\PublishClass\":8:{s:12:\"\u0000*\u0000variables\";a:3:{s:8:\"campusId\";i:1;s:7:\"classId\";i:7837;s:8:\"cohortId\";i:33;}s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";s:8:\"database\";s:5:\"queue\";s:19:\"course_interactions\";s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"}
```

I want to make use of the JSON methods in Mariabd to obtain the classId.

At the moment I use JSON_VALUE but can only get the value linked to command

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(payload, '$.data.command') as t from jobs
```

I need to get the value classId without making use of wildcards of string search.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the json methods returned a string that could not further be manipulated. Had to use other SQL methods to get the classId

```
set @mydata = 's:7';
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING(payload, POSITION(@mydata IN payload) + 18, 10), ';' ,1) SEPARATOR ';') FROM jobs;
```